# Launching Steam, but get error "Could not load module vgui2_s.so"

Tags: drivers, steam

I am trying to launch Steam. I had a missing packages error and resolved that, but now I get the following error message every single time:

[image: Steam error screen: Could not load module 'vgui2_s.so']

I could really use some help on this one, as an alternate post with the same issue had an answer that ended up not working for me.

Comment: That's part of the Steam install, not any Ubuntu package.  Try installing Steam again, from the Ubuntu steam package.

Comment: I just did that, and it didn't do a thing.